# How to append file content with SAF without using FileOutputStream

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

`FileOutputStream` allows to append a file just setting the append attribute to `true` in its constructor, unfortunately with SAF `FileOutputStream` cannot be used due to direct path limitations and file write is something like

```
resolver = getContentResolver();
OutputStream os = resolver.openOutputStream(source_uri);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
out.print(somestring);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

if I use `out.append(somestring);`rather than `out.print(somestring);`the behavior is exactly the same and the content of file is replaced, but I want that new input is appended to existent content of file for each invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two forms of `openOutputStream()`. The one-parameter version that you are using is the equivalent of calling the two-parameter version with a mode of `"w"`. For an append operation, try the two-parameter version with `"wa"` as the mode:

```
OutputStream os = resolver.openOutputStream(source_uri, "wa");
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openOutputStream(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) for more.